# autoLayout in Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am following video swift programming language, today I saw the option about autolayout, as you can see in the picture; then I get an application I already had (the orange buttons) but I can't see the icons of the autolayout under the image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you enable autolayout for your old app? 
- check File Inspector on the right panel, check `Use Autolayout` checkbox

[image]

Comment: I did it... I see Identity and Type section, Project Document Section, Text Settings Section, Source control Section, but no Interface Builder Document

Comment: could you paste what's in your file inspector and make sure if you are with xcode 6

Comment: I move to Main.storyboard and then I saw it